# SharePoint framework to sync network folder

Tags: sharepoint-framework, synchronisation

Can I use the SharePoint framework to synchronise files from a network folder to a document library?  If not the framework is there a way to host some service that will monitor a network drive and pull any changes to a document library.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provide a few ways to synchronise files between your PC and SharePoint/OneDrive for Business.

For Microsoft 365, the OneDrive application allows you to synchronise files between a folder on your PC and a SharePoint document library or OneDrive for Business account:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b

For SharePoint 2013/2016, you may need to use the older OneDrive client (groove.exe):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-client-groove-exe-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd

If you cannot use the above options, you may be able to use Power Automate to achieve this requirement. Using the [File System connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/filesystem/), you can connect to local or network machines. You will need to use the On-Premises Data Gateway to use this connector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However it requires a PC running to connect to OneDrive and then to SharePoint.  I'm looking for a pure server side solution

Comment: The SharePoint framework (SPFx) is purely client side, so I don't think it will help with your requirement. It is not possible to deploy server side code to SharePoint Online, therefore you would need something between SharePoint and your network drive to synchronise files. If it's of any help, the OneDrive application can be installed on Windows Server.

Comment: Does PowerAutomate connect to Windows network drives?

Comment: Yes, you can use the File System connector to connect to network machines. I have updated my answer to include Power Automate. Please let the community know if this answers your question by choosing to accept the answer or alternatively letting us know if it doesn't via a comment.